# What is this Override error and how do I fix it?

Tags: swift

I am making an ios game with a moving character and a rotating weapon, it worked but then I took a month break and ios got an update to 9. My code no longer works and gives me an error. What is the error and more importantly how do I go about fixing it?

```
 override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if (leftButton.containsPoint(location)){
            leftPressed = true
        }else{
            leftPressed = false
        }
        if (rightButton.containsPoint(location)){
            rightPressed = true
        }else{
            rightPressed = false
        }
    }
}
```

That is one of my code snippets that gets the error. Here is the error: Method does not override any method from its superclass

Answer (score 0):

What likely happened is that during the update to iOS 9, the function changed and your implementation is outdated and no longer valid.

Read the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesMoved:withEvent:) (already at the function you are using).

You defined your function as

```
touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

The new implementation is

```
touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
```

Your implementation takes a different data type as an argument and is therefore not the same function and this is why you are getting the override error.